# Batch Script - Detect Drive letter and Execute a File Transfer

Tags: batch-file, data-transfer

I am trying to create a simple batch script to test the Data transfer between two Thumb Drives connected to a Test PC. This is how the test must proceed:

1. Detect if the USB Drives are connected to the PC.
2. If connected, detect the drive letters and assign them as Drive 1 and Drive 2
3. Test the Data Transfer by moving a file from the PC's Hard Drive to Drive 1. Move the same file from Drive 1 to Drive 2. Move the same file from Drive 2 back to the PC.
4. Repeat the same test by moving a file from the PC's Hard Drive to Drive 2. Move the same file from Drive 2 to Drive 1. Move the same file from Drive 1 back to the PC.

So far have managed to create the script (Script1) to detect the drive letters. I also have the script (Script2) to transfer the file as described in Points 3 and 4 (But here, the drive letters are fixed). However, I am not able to use the detected drive letters to transfer my file.

I am looking for a way to combine Script1 and Script2. Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to use the detected drive letters and execute the data transfer between the two?

It would be great if you could suggest an alternative solution as well.

Script1 to detect the drive:

```
@echo off  
for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('fsutil fsinfo drives') do (  
   for %%c in (%%b) do (  
      for /F "tokens=3" %%d in ('fsutil fsinfo drivetype %%c') do (  
         if %%d equ Removable (  
            echo Drive %%c is Removable (USB^)  
         )  
      )  
   )  
)
```

Script2 is a simple script to move a file (fixed name) from one drive to the other:

```
@echo off  
Echo Moving File from PC to USBDrive1  
move E:\Test1.txt   N:\  
Echo Moving File from USBDrive1 to USBDrive2  
move N:\Test1.txt   D:\  
Echo Moving File from USBDrive2 to PC  
move D:\Test1.txt   E:\
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. 
Then you know what we expect from questioners: showing us the code on where you stuck solving the task by yourself and explaining why you fail to complete the task. Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please [edit] your question and share your code.

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40124232/edit) your question and add what did you tried as code until now !